# Why method uses class name as modifier(?) and argument?

Tags: java, class, methods

Below are the 4 methods that I got confused, that 4 methods are in the Teacher class. I have a Student class and Teacher class. and in the Teacher class, declared is the `ArrayList<Student> students` as instance variable.

How to explain the Student that I saw in the methods given below and it is also used as a parameter. I am very confused with the Student `searchStudent` (in the method) and the `Student student` (inside the argument). Is that for `ArrayList` only? How to understand that concept where one class will search another class using the class name?

```
public Student searchStudent(Student student)
{
    //confuses me
    Student found = null;

    if (this.students.contains(student))
    {
        int index = this.students.indexOf(student);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            found = this.students.get(index);
        }
    }
    return found;
}

public Student searchStudent(int id)
{
    //confuses me
    Student beingSearched = new Student();
    beingSearched.setStudentId(id);
    return this.searchStudent(beingSearched);
}

public boolean addStudent(Student student)
{
    //confuses me
    boolean added = false;
    if (this.searchStudent(student) == null)
    {
        this.students.add(student);
        added = true;
    }
    return added;
}

public boolean addStudent(int id, String name, double grade)
{
    //this is fine as i know boolen and int, String and double//
    Student student = new Student(id, name, grade);
    return this.addStudent(student);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advice you to go through [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) about *Defining Methods*.

- `public Student searchStudent(Student student)`

  It's a `public` method that returns an object of type `Student`, it accepts an object of type `Student` as well.
  It needs to accept the `student` parameter because it search for it. You'll use this method when you want to search whether some `student` exists in your records (in the `student` ArrayList).
- `public Student searchStudent(int id)`

  The same, but the parameter it accepts is an `int`. Here you'll search for the `student` not by the object itself, but by the *id* of the `student`.
- `public boolean addStudent(Student student)`

  It's a method that adds a `student` (which is of type `Student`) to `students` ArrayList.

Tip: Run your code in *Debug* mode and follow each method you don't understand, you'll be amazed of how much this will help you to better understand the flow of the program.

Comment: Indeed. I'm in love with debuggers, I debug every thing, even my TV and microwave.